# Center a title when left and right margins are not the same

Tags: margins, titles, geometry

I am using different margins for the left and right side :

```
 \usepackage[
  a4paper,
  top=2cm,
  bottom=2.5cm,
  left=4cm,
  right=3cm,
  headsep=25pt,
  headheight=14.5pt
]{geometry} % Page margins
```

Here is how I generate my title :

```
\author{Me}
\title{Rapport}
\date{today}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
```

When I use the maketitle command, the title is not centered on the page.
How to center it relatively to the page ?

Comment: Are you using the `titlepage environment? Can you show a minimal example?

Comment: I don't know if it is what you asked but I edited my post.

Comment: @Babajaga: What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: @Babajaga It doesn't make much sense to center the title if the text block is shifted to the right.

Comment: I am using extreport
I need to center it because  I have an image as backgroud and the text is not fiting well when it is shiofted.

Comment: Please, make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, this is one of those rare cases in which it is preferable to add another answer, rather then editing the one I already gave; indeed, I dislike my previous answer so much that I’ll probably remove it.  The following, obvious solution is much neater:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  top=2cm,
  bottom=2.5cm,
  left=4cm,
  right=3cm,
  headsep=25pt,
  headheight=14.5pt
]{geometry} % Page margins
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{
  top=2cm,
  bottom=2.5cm,
  left=3cm,
  right=3cm,
  headsep=25pt,
  headheight=14.5pt
}
\begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    \null\vfil
    {\LARGE My Not-so-beautiful document\par}
    \vspace{2pc}
    {\large Etc.\ etc.\par}
    \vfil
    \includegraphics{image}
    \vfil\null  
\end{titlepage}

\restoregeometry

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

The first page looks like this:

[image: Output of sample code]

Comment: The new geometry and restore geometry fixed it, thank you.

Comment: I have deleted my previous answer, as announced.